2012 chevy tahoe headlights(LB) dont work but HB do...question is is the wiring go to ecm first
The headlights (LB) Dont work
Not receiving power...High beams work fine...having trouble locating where power is coming from...does it come from ecm? 2012 chevy tahoe ltz

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

To answer one of your questions, the power does not come from the ECM. I believe the power comes from the body control module (BCM), but not sure.
You need to check the fuses. There are actually two fuses for the low beams, one for each side. These are located under the hood (not in the driver's compartment) on the left side of the engine compartment (driver's side for here in the States). The two fuses you are looking for are 11 & 16.
NOTE: An interactive map can be found at this link.

After you check the fuses, check to ensure there is power at the fuses, too.
If this doesn't pan out, I'd suspect the problem is probably the switch on the column. Both fuses probably wouldn't go out at the same time, but if the switch isn't working, it would affect both of the lights.
